# Custom logger for rails prosopite gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rubygems, select-n-plus-1

How to configure prosopite gem in rails for custom logger file.
I need to separate file for specs and API scan details.
for example:
`prosopite_api.log` file for API scan details.
`prosopite_specs.log` file for Specs scan details.

In the readme file they have provided a way, by passing a custom logger class to `prosopite.custom_logger`, but I do not want to create this custom class and also don't have a need for the separate custom logger class, What I need is just a separate logger file for specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just pass a new instance of the existing logger class with the file name we want.
for example:

```
Prosopite.custom_logger = Logger.new('log/custom_file_name.log')
```

This way I didn't have to create a new custom logger class and configured a separate file for specs(By adding this in `test.rb`).

development.rb:

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Prosopite.prosopite_logger = true
    Prosopite.custom_logger = Rails.logger
  end
```

test.rb

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Prosopite.custom_logger = Logger.new('log/prosopite_specs.log')
  end
```